# How do I efficiently page a large collection of query results with Sails.js / Waterline?

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I'm working with a large dataset behind the Waterline ORM.  In several use-cases I need to do some processing on many/most of the record–10's of thousands.

So far I've been working with `.find()`, but that executes and returns the entire result set.  Is there a Sails/Waterline approach to iterating over a query result–which preserves the storage-agnostic aspect of the ORM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use paginate, something like -> Model.find().paginate({page: xx, limit: xx});

More info here: http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/query-language
Search for pagination :)

Comment: ah, thanks!  I was pretty sure I was overlooking something

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep the *storage agnostic* waterline trait you will have to take a look to your actual schema implementation (**even** if you're coding *storage agnostic*).

You can:

1. Use pagination like @holzanic answers, however this might come up with critital performance issues in some storage technologies.
2. [Use streams.](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/stream)
3. If you will be listing whole objects from a Model, you can make sure you can craft paginate by id. You can take first n elements in a query and then try to obtain the next page where their id attribute is bigger than last received in previous page.